# Troubleshooting why spring bean is not being loaded

Tags: spring-boot

Our class Autowires a StreamBridge bean which is in spring-cloud-stream.jar

It works in a small POC project, however in our large project that is being updated from springboot 2 to 3, we get the error that the bean cannot be found, even though the same jar file is pulled in with the dependencies

Is there a way to enable enhanced logging that can shed more light on why the bean is not being loaded?

Comment: [`debug`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.debug) or [`trace`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.core.trace) from the possible [config properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.core) should help

Comment: If you are upgrading Spring Boot you also need to upgrade Spring Cloud as those are tied to certain Spring Boot versions.